# how to call function with async await in React function, so I can get the result by sequentially

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I have this function that try to call antoher multiple functions to get all data from every functions, and I expected to call each of function sequentially. the problem is I still got the result that the every functions in getAll() not done sequentially. Anybody know how it should've done?

```
_getALL = async () => {
        await this.getA();
        await this.getB();
        await this.getC();
        await this.getD();
      }
```

example one of the functions:

```
getA() {
    getUserA.list()
       .then((res) => {
         const responseData = res.data;
         const Datas = responseData.map(b => ({
           key: b.id,
           name: b.name,
         }));
         this.setState({ users: Datas });
       })
       .catch((err) => {
         console.log( err);
       });
  }
```

I  just started to learn using this async/await metode.any help would be appreciate

Comment: How exactly did you get this result? Because that should run in sequence.

Comment: OK, then it's clear: in `getA`, simply add a `return` before `getUserA`.  The function needs to return a promise for the `await` to work, as it is now, it just returns `undefined`

Comment: @ChrisG yes it is,like sometime getB or getC already get the result before getA done, is there somethings that I missed?

Comment: Like Patrick says, you need to return the promise: `return getUserA.list()...` Also, `this.setState` is asynchronous, so even if getB() runs only after getA() has run, there's no guarantee about the order of the setState calls.

Comment: @PatrickHund,Thanks,but can you please just edit my code to show how exactly it's supposed to be by add a return.I  still don't get it how to add that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await` will only work with functions that return a promise. Your `getA` function currently returns nothing, i.e. `undefined`. You can fix this by adding a `return`, like this:

```
getA() {
    return getUserA.list()
       .then((res) => {
         const responseData = res.data;
         const Datas = responseData.map(b => ({
           key: b.id,
           name: b.name,
         }));
         this.setState({ users: Datas });
       })
       .catch((err) => {
         console.log( err);
       });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure but if your function doesn't have a return when you call this one, this await nothing so it continue the script execution.
Try to return something.